# How to send distributed notification in sandboxed app in Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I can't send distributed notifications in an application that i tried to sandbox in Lion.
Getting…

```
deny distributed-notification-post
```

…in Console's `system.log`. Is there any entitlement that can be added to allow the notifications.

Is it possible to do it and if so how?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to include a user-info dictionary, it should work; if it doesn't, ask on Apple's dev forums and/or file a radar.

But if you do need to include a user-info dictionary, you can't do it, and there is no direct workaround. If you look at the App Sandbox Design Guide, in the section "Determining Whether Your App Is Suitable for Sandboxing", it says:

> The following app behaviors are incompatible with App Sandbox:
>
> ...
>
> - Sending user-info dictionaries in broadcast notifications
>
>   With App Sandbox, you can send notifications, but you cannot include a user-info dictionary in the notifications you send.

So, you'll have to rewrite your app to use some other mechanism for inter-process communication. (The Growl project may be a useful resource, since they went through this before most other people, and out in the open.)